# Is the multivariable function differentiable at (1,0)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y)=\bigg\{\matrix{\frac{\sqrt{1+xy}-1}{y}  &y\not=0\\\frac{x}{2} & y=0}$

I concluded that its partial derivatives are not continuous at (1,0) and the function itself is continuos at this point. Is the only way to solve this is finding the derivate of this function at (1,0)? How should I guess it?

Partial derivatives:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{1 + x y}}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{-2 - x y + 2 \sqrt{1 + x y}}{2 y^2 \sqrt{1 + x y}}$$

Comment: What did you get for the partial derivatives at $(1,0)?$

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: But I was asking about their values at $(1,0)$

Comment: $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,0)}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=-\frac 18$, but $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(1,0)=0$ so it is not continuous. $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is continuous, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $y\ne0$ you have
$$f(x,y)={xy\over y\bigl(\sqrt{1+xy}+1\bigr)}={x\over\sqrt{1+xy}+1}=:g(x,y)\ ,$$
and
$$g(x,0)={x\over2}=f(x,0)\ .$$
It follows that in fact $f=g$, whereby $g$ is unproblematic when $y=0$. This allows to conclude that $f$ is even $C^\infty$ in a neighborhood of $(1,0)$.